# Android Maps v2 Stopped Working

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I've had Google Maps v2 up and running for months, no code has changed, and now every fragment with a MapFragment crashes when attached. (Building without proguard and signing with debug key)

I am guessing that it has to do with Play Services, because it appeared to work after re-installing the Play Services updates. But now it crashes again, even with re-installing. This occurs on two Samsung Note 8s, a Note 3, a Note 1, and a Nexus 5.

I have tried clean builds and regenerating the Maps API with a different Google APIs account.

I've included the necessary bits in my AndroidManifest:

```
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/app_id_maps"/>
```

I include the following xml in the my fragment layouts:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    map:mapType="normal"
    map:uiCompass="true"
    map:uiRotateGestures="true"
    map:uiScrollGestures="true"
    map:uiTiltGestures="true"
    map:uiZoomControls="false"
    map:uiZoomGestures="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Logcat:

```
07-31 08:23:57.721  31926-31926/com.packagename I/u﹕ Making Creator dynamically
07-31 08:23:57.731  31926-31926/com.packagename I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 5077000
07-31 08:23:57.731  31926-31926/com.packagename I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method guj.a, referenced from method gqi.a
07-31 08:23:57.731  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static method 24936: Lguj;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgri;
07-31 08:23:57.731  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
07-31 08:23:57.731  31926-31926/com.packagename E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-31 08:23:57.731  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;
07-31 08:23:57.731  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'gpr', referenced from method gps.a
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpr;) in Lgps;
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0a in Lgps;.a
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0c in Lgps;.a
07-31 08:23:57.736  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea3 at 0x0a in Lgps;.a
07-31 08:23:57.741  31926-31926/com.packagename I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 5084030
07-31 08:23:57.746  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 20873 (t) in Lyp;
07-31 08:23:57.746  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
07-31 08:23:57.746  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 20873 (t) in Lyp;
07-31 08:23:57.746  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
07-31 08:23:57.846  31926-31926/com.packagename I/dalvikvm﹕ Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lgln;'
07-31 08:23:57.846  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
07-31 08:23:57.846  31926-31926/com.packagename E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method glt.a
07-31 08:23:57.846  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lglt;
07-31 08:23:57.846  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0019
07-31 08:23:57.886  31926-31926/com.packagename D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3142K, 31% free 10122K/14616K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
07-31 08:23:57.901  31926-31926/com.packagename D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
07-31 08:23:57.916  31926-32063/com.packagename A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1), thread 32063 (DataRequestDisp)
07-31 08:23:57.921  31926-31926/com.packagename D/ProgressBar﹕ setProgressDrawable drawableHeight = 0
07-31 08:23:57.921  31926-31926/com.packagename D/AbsSeekBar﹕ AbsSeekBar Constructor: misSeebarAnimationAvailable = false
07-31 08:23:57.956  31926-31926/com.packagename W/GmsClientEvents﹕ registerConnectionCallbacks(): listener com.google.android.gms.internal.hc$c@429b29d0 is already registered
07-31 08:23:58.011  31926-31926/com.packagename D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: left = 0
07-31 08:23:58.011  31926-31926/com.packagename D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: top = 0
07-31 08:23:58.011  31926-31926/com.packagename D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: right = 64
07-31 08:23:58.011  31926-31926/com.packagename D/ProgressBar﹕ updateDrawableBounds: bottom = 64
```

On Samsung devices I also get this stacktrace:

```
07-31 08:23:57.656  31926-31926/com.packagename W/dalvikvm﹕ No implementation found for native Ldalvik/system/VMRuntime;.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
07-31 08:23:57.661  31926-31926/com.packagename E/ActivityThread﹕ Pause GC
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc:(Ljava/lang/String;)I
            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.pauseGc(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.pauseGC(ActivityThread.java:5410)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2277)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1280)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5487)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: @Nabin the second log is just additional information I get on some devices. I don't think it's related, since I am getting the same error on other devices, but I thought it would be a good idea to include more info just in case.